# Begin tracing program after some number of instructions have executed

Tags: x86-64, intel, trace, performancecounter, intel-pin

I want to enable tracing in my program after a certain number of instructions have been executed. I can trivially begin tracing at the start of my program but then only start recording after N instructions, but then I'll have the overhead associated with the instructions being instrumented already. I essentially want the program to run at full speed until I am ready to begin tracing.

I am using a pintool to trace the program. I thought perhaps I could use some performance monitoring functionality such as PEBS to accomplish this. Maybe I could wake up after every roughly 10k instructions to see if I have run more than N instructions?

Solutions with other binary instrumentation tools are welcome as well.

Comment: Does PIN support "taking over" after a process has already started executing?  If you need detailed tracing, and PIN can start late, then yes, `perf_event_open` should be able to program the counter for the `instructions` event to raise an interrupt after the specific number of instructions.  (Or some fraction of that if your startup phase is more instructions than the max counter period.)  For sampling profiling mode, the hardware has a down-counter that SW programs with a starting value, and it raises an interrupt (taking a sample) on reaching zero in non-PEBS mode. This is the sample period

Comment: If your CPU supports LBR (last branch record), that's a lower-overhead way to reconstruct the path of execution (although not with register values.)   `perf stat --delay 100` waits 100 milliseconds before it starts recording events.

Comment: I was going to say this:

"I believe I can use Pin "Regions" to enable instrumentation at an arbitrary point in the program, so your first suggestion sounds perfect. Could you be a bit more explicit about how I can set the number of instructions and how I can get the event to raise an interrupt? I'm not seeing much about interrupts on the perf_event_open man page."

But, while I was reading through the Pin Region documentation, I found that the control manager feature it has a built in alarm that can be triggered at a specific instruction count. So I suppose that

Comment: I'm pretty sure the hardware supports interrupting after s programmed number of counts for any event, including instructions, but I don't know how to to access that from user-space via `perf_event_open`, like getting a user-space signal.  If you can set it to wake up user-space for every sample recorded, setting the sample period to the count you want could do it, with the counter programmed to count only in user-space so you don't count kernel instructions.